# Is this welcoming behavior?

Tags: discussion

Just now, I came across this question: [Structure AWS environment following best practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400422/structure-aws-environment-following-best-practices)

> I have recently completed "AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner 2019" from aCloud.Guru. The course essentially gives you an idea of the different AWS services and some best practices for using along with some practical examples which you can follow along with e.g. deploy Wordpress site to AWS.
>
> Ultimately I'm now left with some knowledge but no "real" experience. My goal is to deploy a default install of nopCommerce 4.20 and have an environment that would be useful for a small business. My idea is to use AWS Organisations and have 4 accounts managing specific tasks - each account with have the minimum privileges to complete its role. - dev would have write only into global (to pass logs)
>
> What I would like to know is what should I take in to consideration to work out if i'm missing anything? or is there anything that you would usually expect to see in this type of setup, that I have missed of my design?
>
> Should security have a separate account and if so what services should I include?
>
> Finally I am trying to keep costs as low as possible so need to trying to keep an eye on costs so some options are defiantly out. I want to mimic a business environment but this will be coming out of my own pocket so my options have a some limitations

The person who asked obviously put some time into writing that.  They even made a diagram.  It's not spam.  It's not abusive.  It's not a homework question.  Looking at the user's profile, they've currently got 1.3k rep on Stack Overflew, so they aren't a clueless newbie either.

Is the question on topic?  Probably not, but that's not what I am asking about.  The question currently has a score of -2, with three close votes.  And no comments.  Nothing.  Not a word to this user, new to Software Engineering, but not Stack Overflow, about what they did wrong.

How do people expect that would make someone feel?  Welcomed?  Or that this is an exclusive place where the cold shoulder and the silent rejection is the norm.

My suspicion is that we'll never see tony09uk here again.  Is that the best outcome here?  Is that what the users on this site want?  If someone spent twenty minutes crafting a well intentioned post, don't they deserve more than silence?

I think it might be worth people's whole to peruse the [user's history](https://stackexchange.com/users/1444200/tony09uk?tab=accounts) and see how they were received on other stack exchange sites.  It doesn't particularly reflect well on this one.

Clarification:

**This question is explicitly NOT asking why the question was closed or downvoted.**

Comment: Honestly, I've found this stack exchange in particularly to be pretty downvote happy. It's not a pleasant experience posting here.

Comment: To paraphrase  Nick Lowe, "you gotta to be cruel to be kind".  At least on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is two-fold:

- why was the question in stake downvoted / closed? *(Yes, you added afterwards that you don't want this to be answered, but I think since your question shows a misunderstanding about the reason, it deserves an answer to this part anyway.)*
- why did no one care to write a comment?

Let me start with the first one. The question in stake is IMHO way too vague and broad for the Q&A format of this site, so I think it is not astonishing it was closed.  Other experts on this site [think quite similar](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad) about this, and askers, when they are new to this site, should definitely read the [on-topic section of the help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. The [off-topic section](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) has also some good advice, it says

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

(Disclaimer: as you now can see, I did not close-vote on this question, and also did not downvote so far, but I guess if I had seen the question earlier, as long as it was open, I would have cast a close-vote for myself too, for the reasons above).

To the second point: people here often don't take the time for writing a comment when close-voting such questions, because the site get tons of low quality questions every week. Instead, they often rely on the precanned comment which is generated when after the closing actually happen. That is indeed debatable, but IMHO legitimate. What I [personally dislike](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/can-we-improve-our-style-of-self-moderation-for-not-too-bad-questions) is, when questions which could have a chance to get saved with some edits are treated like this. But the question in stake is so broad I don't see how it could easily be salvaged without making it a completely different question. And when I am not able to give any constructive critics for this reason, I would usually just close-vote, too, without commenting.

Unfortunately, the system does not show the close reason explanation to the OP before a question gets actually closed, either by five close-voters or a mod (note this was the case at the time when you asked this meta question). In between the reason for the close-votes is hopefully more apparent.

About the downvotes: those are necessary to finally delete the question without the help of a mod, people should not take them so personally.

Comment: My question is explicitly *not* "why was the question downvoted / closed".  In fact, I explicitly state "Is the question on topic? Probably not..."   Beyond that, your answer seems to miss the core of the question, which you only really address in last seven words.

Comment: @GorttheRobot: it seems you are complaining because I tried to give you a full picture of the case. The question *is* on-topic, but that is not why it is closed for, that's why I think you deserve an explanation (part 1 of my answer), since your question makes this wrong assumption. And you explictly asked why the close/downvotes are not accompanied by a comment. That is part 2 of my answer. If you are not satisfied, I think I cannot help you with this.

Comment: The only assumptions the question makes on the "why" of the close vote is "It's not spam. It's not abusive. It's not a homework question."   Is one of those things the case?

Comment: (The title of the question is not rhetorical: it is the question being asked)

Comment: (With this also being seen as the core question: "How do people expect that would make someone feel? Welcomed? Or that this is an exclusive place where the cold shoulder and the silent rejection is the norm.")

Comment: @GorttheRobot: Unfortunately, we can't afford to mollycoddle everyone who stumbles into this site and asks a book-sized question.  There's plenty of information available to everyone who visits here to make their question-asking experience successful.  Downvotes and close votes *are not personal;* they are directed at the post, not the person.

Comment: Back to History for me then, I guess.

Comment: (I prefer that site because even the [worst](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55155/how-were-the-beds-in-which-privileged-man-in-medieval-europe-slept) [questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55175/why-is-it-claimed-that-soldiers-were-the-first-to-shoot-when-it-was-reported-tha) get feedback.)

Comment: @GorttheRobot: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9017/whats-wrong-with-this-question-about-react-event-handling-conventions#comment28093_9018

Comment: My question was basically about whether a drive-by downvote is "nice".  I don't think it is, but I also don't think it's cricket to answer my own question, so I'm basically just going to leave.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is only so much you can ask of people who volunteer their time on a Q&A site.

To answer your question: having your question down-voted and closed isn't very welcoming, but it's certainly not personal or malicious.

In my opinion, the question you quote falls into a category I see with some frequency here, wherein:

- the topic is very broad
- it includes multiple, different questions

It's difficult to know where to begin answering questions like these, and commenting can sometimes lead to a prolonged discussion which requires too much time.