# How can I improve this question about software architecture?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have recently posted [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/414361/where-should-i-place-more-complex-business-logic-related-to-what-a-web-api-does) which quickly attracted downvotes and close votes. Some were accompanied by useful comments that helped me edit it to avoid some pitfalls (e.g. pros and cons).

However, it is still not clear what is this question missing.

**Question:** How can I improve it to be on-topic and answerable?

P.S. I do not know if it is possible in this community (e.g. high question volume?), I have seen experienced members helping (mainly comments, but also edits) the newbie to shape good questions out of mediocre ones (example [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/54898/revisions) or [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/54798/revisions) or [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/18188/revisions)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is perfectly on-topic, and the (currently) one downvote should not bother you. There are some individuals in the community here who are very resistant against any arguments I brought up in [one of my former meta posts](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/can-we-improve-our-style-of-self-moderation-for-not-too-bad-questions). Note also the question already got 3 upvotes for now.

However, the text was not easy to read for me, because it

- contains a lot of information where it is not inherently clear if it is really needed
- does not contain much information on the used technologies
- jumps a little between the terms "monolith", a "SPA", a "Web API", then an "internal application" (is the monolith meant?) and an external one (the SPA?)

But don't bother, after reading the question slowly again, I guess I finally got it and managed to write an answer. So alas, leave it as it is, don't overthink it.

Answer (score 3):

Down votes and close votes do not necessarily mean your question is bad. *Every single question* yesterday attracted down votes and/or close votes. Some people answer in comments instead of answers because they don't want to attract down votes on their answer.

Comment: This might make more sense for a meta site where downvotes are linked to disagreement with the post. The downvote button tooltip says to use it if the question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: Ref. "Every single question yesterday attracted down votes and/or close votes. Some people answer in comments instead of answers because they don't want to attract down votes on their answer." - this is an interesting insight, but it also means it is quite hard for newbies around here.